# Gremlin get vertices with minimum number of incoming edgers of a particular edge type

Tags: gremlin

So I have a graph with 'people' nodes and 'meeting' nodes.
The edge can be of either  "Call In"  or Call"Out"

I trying to get all the names of the persons
    that have more than 2 edges of type "Called In"
    from meetings that occurred in the last 30 days?

I've got this, but how do I work in the dates?

```
g.V().has("label", "person").where(out('Called In').count().is(gt(5))).values('name')
```

thanks

[image]

Comment: How do you store the dates? One option is to use Unix date stored as long.

Answer (score 3):

If `MeetingDate` is stored as a `Long` (days since epoch), it would be:

```
g.V().hasLabel("person").
  filter(out("Called In").
           has("MeetingDate", gte(LocalDate.now().minusDays(30).toEpochDay())).
         count().is(gt(2))).
 values("name")
```

If `MeetingDate` is stored is a `String`, it has to be in the US format (`yyyy-MM-dd`), otherwise, `gte` (and all other range predicates) won't work.

Next, if the date is indexed, you would rather do the following in order to get the best traversal performance:

```
g.V().has("Meeting","MeetingDate",gte(LocalDate.now().minusDays(30).toEpochDay())).
  in("Called In").dedup().
  values("name")
```